# making all possible combination in Python and also use of google API for csv/xlsx file

Tags: python, excel, csv, google-api, file-handling

I have to write a script in python that will do following actions 
I have a xlsx/csv file in which there are 300 cities listed in one column

1. I have to make all pairs between them and also with help of google api I have to add their distance and travel time in the second column

my **CSV file** is looks like this:

```
=======
SOURCE 
=======
Agra 
Delhi 
Jaipur
```

and expected output **in csv/xlsx file** be like this

```
=============================================
SOURCE | DESTINATION | DISTANCE | TIME_TRAVEL
=============================================
Agra   |    Delhi    |    247   |      4    
Agra   |    Jaipur   |    238   |      4    
Delhi  |    Agra     |    247   |      4    
Delhi  |    jaipur   |    281   |      5
Jaipur |    Agra     |    238   |      4    
Jaipur |    Delhi    |    281   |      5
```

and so on.. how to do this.?
**NOTE**: Distance and Travel Time are from google.

Comment: Are the cities starting at line 3 in your file?

Comment: I can delete the heading. and after running the script I can add the heading It's only one line. It is in question because it will make more clear. So cities are starting from top

Comment: Your problem cannot be tested, so that's the best I could do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the pairs you can use itertools.permutations to get all possible pairs.
Code for the same would be as :

```
import csv     # imports the csv module
import sys      # imports the sys module
import ast
import itertools    
source_list = []
destination_list = []
type_list = []list
f = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')
g = open(sys.argv[2], 'wb')
 # opens the csv file
try:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    my_list = list(reader) # creates the reader object
    for i in my_list:
        source_list.append(i[0])
    a = list(itertools.permutations(source_list, 2))
    for i in a:
        source_list.append(i[0])
        destination_list.append(i[1])
    mywriter=csv.writer(g)
    rows = zip(source_list,destination_list)
    mywriter.writerows(rows)
    g.close()

finally:
    f.close()
```

Apart from that to get distance and time from the google this sample code may work for full debugging.

```
import csv     # imports the csv module
import sys      # imports the sys module
import urllib2,json
import ast  
api_google_key = ''
api_google_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins='
source_list = []
destination_list = []
distance_list = []
duration_list = []
f = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')
g = open(sys.argv[2], 'wb')
 # opens the csv file
try:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    my_list = list(reader) # creates the reader object
    for i in my_list:
    if i:
            s = (i[0])
        src = s.replace(" ","")
            d = (i[1])
        dest = d.replace(" ","")
        source = ''.join(e for e in src if e.isalnum())
        destination = ''.join(e for e in dest if e.isalnum())
        print 'source status = '+str(source.isalnum())
        print 'dest status = '+str(destination.isalnum())
        source_list.append(source)
            destination_list.append(destination)
            request = api_google_url+source+'&destinations='+destination+'&key='+api_google_key
        print request
            dist = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(request))
        if dist['rows']:
                if 'duration' in dist['rows'][0]['elements'][0].keys():
                        duration_dict = dist['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text']
                        distance_dict = dist['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text']
                else:
                    duration_dict = 0
                    distance_dict = 0
        else:
                duration_dict = 0
                distance_dict = 0

            distance_list.append(distance_dict)
            duration_list.append(duration_dict)
    mywriter=csv.writer(g)
    rows = zip(source_list,destination_list,distance_list,duration_list)
    mywriter.writerows(rows)
    g.close()

finally:
    f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It Works. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the combinations with `itertools.permutations()` like so:

```
from itertools import permutations

with open(cities_file, 'r') as f, open(newfile, 'w') as f2:
    for pair in (permutations([a.strip() for a in f.read().splitlines()], 2)):
        print pair
        response = googleapi.get(pair)
        f2.write(response+'\n')
```

Output of `print pair`

```
('Agra', 'Delhi')
('Agra', 'Jaipur')
('Delhi', 'Agra')
('Delhi', 'Jaipur')
('Jaipur', 'Agra')
('Jaipur', 'Delhi')
```

You can then hit the api from the list elements 1 by 1 and keep storing the result in the file.

Comment: Thanks I will try this. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `itertools.product` but that'll mean that you'll also get repetitions like `(Agra, Agra)` the distance for which will be 0 really.

```
import itertools
cities = ["Agra","Delhi","Jaipur"]
cities2 = cities
p = itertools.product(cities, cities2)
print(list(p))
```

In this case you'd get

```
[('Agra', 'Agra'), ('Agra', 'Delhi'), ('Agra', 'Jaipur'), ('Delhi', 'Agra'), ('Delhi', 'Delhi'), ('Delhi', 'Jaipur'), ('Jaipur', 'Agra'), ('Jaipur', 'Delhi'), ('Jaipur', 'Jaipur')]
```

You can take loop in this forlist and make a request to google to get the travel time and distance.

```
>>> for pair in list(p):
...     print (pair)
...
('Agra', 'Agra')
('Agra', 'Delhi')
('Agra', 'Jaipur')
('Delhi', 'Agra')
('Delhi', 'Delhi')
('Delhi', 'Jaipur')
('Jaipur', 'Agra')
('Jaipur', 'Delhi')
('Jaipur', 'Jaipur')
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. :)